# Messages remain unread

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sms

I have three messages which show up as unread, even after I open them. The messages icon does not show any unread messages, and the message status persists even after I restart the phone.

Apparently related: this started just after I got a group message which was to (among others) the three people whose messages are now permanently unread. The group MMS itself is marked as read, though.

Comment: What  app are you using? Is it SMS, MMS, IM, email?

Comment: @RossC: SMS (as tagged). In my interface it's just labeled "Messaging".

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the tag due to blindness/stupidity! First thing I'd try is a different SMS app (hangous, go sms or whatever) and see if the issue persists, if so then contact your carrier. I've had this issue and it's usually the network, but some apps just go nuts sometimes!

Comment: I see this same issue. I cannot find a place to file bug reports for Google Messaging.

Comment: Was this solved meanwhile (e.g. due to some updates)? If so, please remember you always can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/192154) :)

Comment: @Izzy: No, not even after all this time! I'd love to know the answer.

Comment: Sure you'd love to! Not that I have it. Is your device rooted?

Comment: @Izzy: No, it's not rooted.

Comment: Oh. That kills the only idea I've had then. I assume you've tried with several [alternative SMS apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_shortmessage) since, haven't you?

Comment: @Izzy: No, I've just stuck with the buggy standard app. I guess I could try that.

Comment: You definitely should. Maybe you'll like the new one even better (I've read [8sms](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkleft.eightyeightsms.mms) should be a pretty good choice, and can even be made the "default messaging app" if you want that); if not, just use it to mark those messages read and return to what you like more :)